# Django/Python calculate comments/votes in HTML templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to `log in` a user and print all the latest `10 articles` along with the `number of comments` and `number of votes`.
My `views.py` for that function goes like this:

```
article_query=Article.objects.filter(creator=user.id)
    article = Article.objects.all()
    latest_articles = article.order_by('-pub_date')
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'article_user': article_query, 'user_info':user_info, 'latest_articles':latest_articles}, RequestContext(request))
```

However, I don't have a dedicated section as `vote_count` or `comment_count` stored in the database. I'm just storing the `ids` of the users that may have voted or commented separated by a semicolon (`;`)in a text field. Eg. votes--> (2;4;6;)

How can I output the number of votes in the template? Should I have to make a dedicated cell as `votes_count` in the database or should I achieve this by coding some cumbersome function in the views file and then displaying it? Which is the conventional method for websites having millions of users?

Comment: Why don't you store Comments and Votes as dedicated objects, and then use the reverse relationship provided by Django ? IDs stored in text field is just a stupid horrifical idea..

Comment: @pistache: Okay. Thanks. I also thought of the same things but wondered as my database getting flooded with too many objects.

Comment: As soon as these objects are well structured and your database well prepared it won't get flooded.